# systemd - only run service after internet is up

Tags: server, 20.04, python, systemd, reboot

```
[Unit]
Description=Twitter notifier daemon
# https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/#cutthecraphowdoimakenetwork.targetworkforme
After=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Requires=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/twitter_streams/venv/bin/python -m twitter.notifier
KillSignal=SIGINT
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**systemd + ubuntu server 20.04 LTS**

I wrote a python script - a twitter client that forwards messages from twitter to slack.

The problem is that whenever the system is rebooted, my script fails to run properly because it tries to connect to the twitter API before the internet is available. It does work fine if I enable it or restart it, just doesn't work on system startup or reboot.

I tried to require (alone & together):

```
network-online.target
systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is the interface(s) [managed](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.html) by systemd-networkd?

Comment: yes, I checked it's using systemd-networkd and not NetworkManager (the latter is not installed on ubuntu server at all)

Answer (score 3):

## Quirky solution:

Stumbled upon the same problem, found a quirky solution.

If you add this to the Service part of your service file, it will loop untill it gets a response from twitter.

```
ExecStartPre= /bin/sh -c 'until ping -c1 twitter.com; do sleep 1; done;'
```

### Explanation:

Only when the ping command gets a response he will continue with your ExecStart.

This means that you will definitely have a network connection, before starting your script.

Only downside is that everytime you start or restart the service, he will ping twitter.com.

### Link:

More information: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57469241)!

Comment: Sometimes the direct hack is worth a million broken "correct" solutions.